# URI not registered Android studio error

Tags: android, xsd, settings, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I have Just installed `android studio` on my computer and I tried to create a new application with the default options selected.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The above is the code which was auto-generated in my `main.xml` file but I get the error as

```
URI is not registered ( Setting | Project Settings | Schemas and DTDs )
```

on the folllowing 2 lines

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

I have tried searching for the solution of this problem but couldn't get a proper answer.
Anyone please help in solving this error.
Thank you.

Comment: I experience the exact same issue here. If I ignore those namespaces, i get an error that the manifest tag does not exist. 
If i build the project with gradle in the commandline everything works fine, only AS throws me this error.

Comment: @Mike Google should provide a better step by step installation and I guess many are facing this error, if you found a solution then let know

Comment: Well the weird thing is, that it worked the last 3 days just fine. And suddenly I cannot build from AS anymore. Re-importing the gradle project fixed it temporarily but now I am stuck again. There are answers to that problem but so far none of them worked for me.

Comment: Well i just uninstalled AS 0.3.5 and installed the official version from google 0.3.1, and everything works again.

I like the AS IDE, but with bugs like these it is just slowing me down. br

Comment: @MikeT Thanks. I will also try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by updating the `Android Studio` to the latest available version.
Thanks.

Comment: Not cool to just downvote without an explanation, @syn3sthete was trying to provide the answer that worked for him.

Comment: I'm using the newest version and I still have the same problem.

Comment: @Menma I have written what worked for me, should I write in detail as how I updated Android studio?
What explanation are you expecting?

Answer (score -1):

Just clear the Temporary files by

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (RUN COMMAND )
2. Type and enter `%temp%`
3. Delete all files
4. Restart android studio.

That's it !